# Choosing GTFS editor for creating and exporting routes?

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations, transportation, general-transit-feed-specification, planning

I am a beginner and I need information about GTFS editors. I want to create routes,trips,patterns,etc... and export it to GTFS-format.

I have setup locally two GTFS editors:

- [TransitDataFeeder](http://www.trilliumtransit.com/2010/08/21/transitdatafeeder-open-source-web-based-gtfs-creation-and-maintenance-tool/)
- [conveyal-gtfs-editor](https://github.com/conveyal/gtfs-editor)

In TransitDataFeeder we need to create each file seperately through UI. I have created a sample agency and created a trip,route and exported it but its not containing the trips and as per my experience TransitDataFeeder does not meet my requirements for creating and editing GTFS.

I have setup [conveyal-GTFS-Editor](https://github.com/conveyal/gtfs-editor) locally and trying to create new route in which its not possible to create trips **using timetable** option. I don't have experience with the play framework. I am trying to debug it but not able to solve it.

From above two, conveyal-gtfs-editor appears to meet my requirements but it is also in development phase so having problems as I saw in [this blog](http://pleasantprogrammer.com/posts/gtfs-editor.html) .

**So I am looking for best alternative to conveyal-gtfs-editor** or need help to resolve conveyal-gtfs-editor with use time-table functionality.

Answer (score 10):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
> because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
> and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
> should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
> type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
> site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
> to do so by editing this answer.

---

A list GTFS Editors I've looked at. If I have to recommend, I'd say go for the commercial ones.

(1) **Free GTFS Editors**

- [TransitFeed](https://github.com/google/transitfeed) A Python library for reading, validating, and writing transit schedule information in the GTFS format. Not really a GTFS Editor, but very useful to make sure the GTFS feed you are editing is sane. Many GTFS Editor shows insane result when the GTFS feed has validation errors. Download from [TransitFeed latest releases](https://github.com/google/transitfeed/releases).
- [XLS Tools for GTFS](https://sites.google.com/site/rheitzman/) excel spreadsheet, Bob Heitzman. Free.
- [GTFS Builder](http://webbuilder.nationalrtap.org/WebApps/GTFSBuilder.aspx) web and excel spreadsheet, National RTAP & The Marcy Jaffe Company, US. Free only for US transit agencies?
- [WikiTimetable](http://wikitimetable.com/Gee/Eric.html) / [Gee](http://gee.chalo.org.uk/Gee/Eric.html) web based, Mark Lester, UK, request to try. Alpha version.
- [yTransit](http://www.ypass.net/yTransit/) web based, yPass US. Free? Alpha version. Blog posts about it, [June 2009](http://www.ypass.net/blog/2009/06/an-app-to-manage-busrail-routes-in-gtfs-format-that-no-one-wanted/) and [July 2011](http://www.ypass.net/blog/2011/07/ytransit-and-gtfs-revisited/)
- [TransLoc Architect](http://transloc.com/architect-free-gtfs-builder/) web and map based, from US. Apply for free account. Create, update, manage, validate, export GTFS.
- [WRI Cities Static GTFS Manager](https://github.com/WRI-Cities/static-GTFS-manager) GUI interface for creating, editing, exporting of static GTFS data for a public transit authority.

(2) **Commercial GTFS Editors**

- [TransitEditor](http://www.transiteditor.com/?q=en/home) web based, i2MApp Innovación, Spain, reguest to try for free.
- [Mobilibus Editor](http://www.mobilibus.com.br/) web based, Mobilibus, Brazil, commercial service?. Looks very similar to [Moovit's GTFS editor](http://editor.moovitapp.com)  .
- [GTFS Manager](http://www.trilliumtransit.com/services/gtfs/#web_based_maintenance) web based, GTFS Manager, Trillium, commercial service.
- [Modes Update](http://www.crc-corp.com/Products/#Transit) web based, Modes Update, Castle Rock, US, commercial service
- [AddTransit GTFS Editor/Builder](https://addtransit.com/gtfs-transit-file.php) web based, commercial service
- [Urbineris](http://urbineris.mecatran.com/en/) web based, developed by Mecatran (France), commercial service

(3) **Developers-friendly GTFS Editors**

- [IBI groups's transit data tools suite](https://github.com/conveyal/gtfs-editor) requires deployment of a Java-based backend using PostgreSQL and MongoDB and a Javascript frontend using Node/npm/React/Redux.
- [TransitDataFeeder](https://code.google.com/p/transitdatafeeder/) require installation of webserver jboss postgres etc. Ref [Trillium's TDF page](http://www.trilliumtransit.com/2010/08/21/transitdatafeeder-open-source-web-based-gtfs-creation-and-maintenance-tool/) and [Google Group discussion on TDF Installation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/transitdatafeeder/BxCFVFRefqk)
- [Node-GTFS](https://github.com/brendannee/node-gtfs) loads transit data in GTFS format from GTFS Data Exchange, unzips it and stores it to a MongoDB database and provides some methods to query for agencies, routes, stops and times. It also has spatial queries to find nearby stops, routes and agencies.
- [Gtfslib-python](https://github.com/afimb/gtfslib-python) An open-source library in python for reading GTFS files and storing them in database, using SQLAlchemy (AFIMB/Mecatran).

---

Static GTFS Manager: https://github.com/WRI-Cities/static-GTFS-manager.

USP: Works plug-and-play on a windows laptop, no installations needed.